# MySQL: DROP a column with a question mark sign?

Tags: mysql, sql-drop

I am trying to drop a column which has a question mark sign:

```
ALTER TABLE player DROP is_playing?;
```

Result:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 2
```

Do you know other ways to drop it?

Thanks

Comment: It is REALLY BAD idea to use question mark in column name. Better change it or You may have alot of problems.

Comment: I can certainly understand not yet knowing about quoting, but if you don't know about that, how did you manage to create this column in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use backticks to escape column or tables names with special names or names of [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

And use the `column` keyword:

```
ALTER TABLE player DROP column `is_playing?`;
```